# How to Select Highest Value Folder Name in Powershell Using Wildcards?

Tags: windows, powershell, script, google-drive, wildcards

I'm writing a script to kill and restart Google Drive for desktop. I also need it to account for new versions. On my test machine, the executable was stored in:

`C:\Program Files\Google\Drive File Stream\51.0.16.0`

The issue comes in when testing on a production machine that's had Drive installed for a while. Turns out Google drive doesn't replace version folders when it updates, rather it just adds another folder with the new version number as seen here:

```
PS C:\Program Files\Google\Drive File Stream> DIR


    Directory: C:\Program Files\Google\Drive File Stream


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----         9/16/2021   9:08 AM                51.0.14.0
d-----        10/15/2021  10:15 AM                51.0.16.0
d-----         9/10/2021  10:56 AM                51.0.9.0
d-----        10/20/2021  12:15 PM                52.0.6.0
d-----         9/10/2021  10:56 AM                Drivers
-a----        12/31/1979  11:00 PM         285478 docs.ico
-a----        12/31/1979  11:00 PM          22721 drive_fs.ico
-a----        12/31/1979  11:00 PM           1544 launch.bat
-a----        12/31/1979  11:00 PM         285478 sheets.ico
-a----        12/31/1979  11:00 PM         285478 slides.ico
```

I've been using wildcards to select the folder the exe is in under the assumption that the old version folder would be overwritten in update using the line:

```ps
Start-Process  "C:\Program Files\Google\Drive File Stream\[0-9]*.*\GoogleDriveFS.exe"
```

How do I get the script to account for new versions? I can't figure out how to get it to select the newest version.

Here's the full script for context:

```ps
#Get Drive Process
$drive = Get-Process -Name "GoogleDriveFS" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
if ($drive) {
    write "`n`nGoogle Drive is currently running. Shutting down Google Drive...`n`n"

    #Stop Drive
    $drive | Stop-Process

    #Wait 5 Seconds
    sleep 5

    #Check to see if its dead
    if(!$drive){
        write "`n`nGoogle Drive has successfully shut down, restarting Google Drive...`n"

        #Restart Drive
        Start-Process  "C:\Program Files\Google\Drive File Stream\[0-9]*.*\GoogleDriveFS.exe"

        #Wait 3 Seconds
        sleep 3

        #Check if Drive is running and display error message if it's not
        if ($drive) {
            write "`n`nGoogle Drive has successfully restarted."
        }

        else {
            write "`n`nGoogle Drive did not restart correctly. Please contact IT"
        }
    }
}

# Drive was not running to begin with
else {
    #Should I use:
    #        elseif ($drive -eq $null) instead?


    #Start Drive
    write "`n`nGoogle Drive is not running, Starting Google Drive..."
    Start-Process  "C:\Program Files\Google\Drive File Stream\[0-9]*.*\GoogleDriveFS.exe"

    #Wait 5 Seconds
    sleep 5

    #check
    if($drive) {
        write "`n`nGoogle Drive has successfully started.`n"
    }
 }

 write "`n`nThe Script is Complete"
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to [Lee_Dailey](https://superuser.com/users/962415/lee-dailey) for helping me find the path. Though there are multiple processes spawned. How do I get just one of them? I can't get the process to start using just the output `Select-Object Path`.

```ps
PS C:\Users\Law Clerk> Get-Process -Name "GoogleDriveFS" | Select-Object -Property Name, Id, Path

Name             Id Path                                                                
----             -- ----                                                                
GoogleDriveFS 11216 C:\Program Files\Google\Drive File Stream\52.0.6.0\GoogleDriveFS.exe
GoogleDriveFS 11368 C:\Program Files\Google\Drive File Stream\52.0.6.0\GoogleDriveFS.exe
GoogleDriveFS 21764 C:\Program Files\Google\Drive File Stream\52.0.6.0\GoogleDriveFS.exe
GoogleDriveFS 25184 C:\Program Files\Google\Drive File Stream\52.0.6.0\GoogleDriveFS.exe
GoogleDriveFS 25356 C:\Program Files\Google\Drive File Stream\52.0.6.0\GoogleDriveFS.exe
GoogleDriveFS 25676 C:\Program Files\Google\Drive File Stream\52.0.6.0\GoogleDriveFS.exe
GoogleDriveFS 27016 C:\Program Files\Google\Drive File Stream\52.0.6.0\GoogleDriveFS.exe
```

Comment: the path for a process is available when you call `Get-Process` [at least when you run in admin mode]. why don't you use that? [*grin*]

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the idea. It also looks like I don't have to be admin to see it either using `Select-Object Path` :)

But Drive spawns multiple processes and I don't know how to extract a single value from the output. Any suggestions? Thx

Comment: I added an what I mean to the body of the question

Comment: that is an array of processes [*grin*] ... so just grab the 1st one. either use the array index OR use `Select-Object -First 1`.